# Have default string resource file and override it with custom ones

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So the title is perhaps not completly clear.
I have a Strings.xaml file which contains several strings which are used in the application.

**Strings.xaml**

```
    <!-- GENERAL FOR ALL TESTS -->
    <my:String x:Key="AppTitle">AppName</my:String>        
    <my:String x:Key="TestName1">test_1</my:String>
    <my:String x:Key="TestName2">test_2</my:String>

    <!-- DEFAULT MESSAGES -->
    <my:String x:Key="TestMessage">This is a default message</my:String>
    <my:String x:Key="TestDescription">This is a default description</my:String>

    <my:String x:Key="OnlyCustomInTest2">This string is used as a default message if not overridden by custom resource file</my:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This resource file works great. What I'm wondering is if there is any built in way that I can use `Strings.xaml` as a default resource file and then override specific strings that are custom for different program modes? Like having `Strings.xaml` default and use `Test_1_Strings.xaml` and `Test_2_Strings.xaml` to override some strings for custom messages.

**Test_1_Strings.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- CUSTOM FOR TEST 1 -->
    <my:String x:Key="TestMessage">This is a message for test 1</my:String>
    <my:String x:Key="TestDescription">This is a description for test 2</my:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Test_2_Strings.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- CUSTOM FOR TEST 2 -->
    <my:String x:Key="TestMessage">This is a message for test 2</my:String>
    <my:String x:Key="TestDescription">This is a description for test 2</my:String>
    <my:String x:Key="OnlyCustomInTest2">This is the overridden message for test 2</my:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have many different program modes where most of the resources are the same but some are custom. Instead of having to change a shared entry in 8 different resource files I could do it in only one place.

Comment: google **resx markup extension** it might give you some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resource lookup in WPF traverses from bottom to top** i.e. any resource usage will first look for resource in its parent container which can be Grid, StackPanel etc. If not found in parent container will look for resource in parent's parent container and so on to UserControl, Window till it reach App resources.

Also, **any resource later defined under resources section overrides the resource added previously with same key**. This is true for resources defined under different resource dictionaries but not within the same XAML file. If you try to declare two items with same key, it will fail with key already exists exception.

---

You can take advantage of above stated features to your use.

Assuming you are merging the resources under App resources, what you can do is add `Strings.xaml` at top and then add other resource dictionaries `Test_1_Strings.xaml` and `Test_2_Strings.xaml`. This way resources with same name will be overridden and resource defined at last will always be resolved.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Strings.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Test_1_Strings.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Test_2_Strings.xaml"/>
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

So when you declare `TextBlock` to refer to StaticResource `TestMessage`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource TestMessage}"/>
```

it will print **`This is a message for test 2`**.

If you change the order and add Test_1 after Test_2, textBlock Text will be  - **`This is a message for test 1`**.

Comment: Intersting, gonna give this a try tomorrow!

Comment: Tried this now and it works perfectly, thanks a lot!